# Facebook graph api v2.4 not returning birthday

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get facebook user birthday. So far I am successfully getting user first_name, last_name,email,name,gender except birthday

```
self.loginButton.publishPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_friends"];
self.loginButton.delegate =self;
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) { 

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields" : @"first_name, last_name,email,name,gender,birthday"}]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the Permission of `user_birthday` in your code,

```
self.loginButton.publishPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_friends",@"user_birthday"];
```

Without above permission in V 2.4 you get only `name` and `id` from facebook,

Check Facebook developer site [Graph Exploror](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Without permission of `user_birthday` , got an error,

[image]

Comment: still i'm not getting birthday

self.loginButton.publishPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_friends",@"user_birthday"];

Comment: Check in your Graph Exploror got Birth date or not.

Comment: Graph Explorer i 'm getting birthday date, browser it works proper

Comment: ok, You have to put your Apps In Facebook Review to get permission from facebook.